# How to add additional tables to an existing code first from database EF model?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

When creating a new entity data model from an existing database using **code first from database** approach, one can directly specify which tables to include in the model. A subset (or all) tables can be selected in the Visual Studio wizard:

[image: EF Data Model Wizard]

In this example, `Category` and `Product` classes will be created along with the `DbContext` derived context class. **If I later want to add additional tables to the same model, is there a simple way to add them, i.e. without having to manually create the classes myself?**

E.g. initially, my `DbContext` class will contain:

```
public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
```

Now suppose I also want to include `Employee` table so that the `DbContext` class will be updated to:

```
public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
```

VS context menus don't seem to provide this option, but maybe I'm missing something. Is there a way to bring back the wizard so I can select additional tables?

One solution is to have a separate empty project where you simply create a new model and then copy/paste new classes, but I'm curious if there's a faster way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. You must run the wizard again, and generate the desired classes.

Comment: Thank you. Do you perhaps know if there is any specific technical or design reason for this? It seems to me that implementing something like this should be pretty straightforward, so it's kind of weird that it's missing from VS.

Comment: I think the team just never got around to it. What is the issue you are facing with simply generating the files again? I cannnot see a big difference in that workflow and what you are asking for...

Comment: The issue (that I didn't mention originally) is that I rename some of the default names (e.g. table name in my specific case may be customer_data while I want the class to be named CustomerData) and provide `Table` attributes, i.e. I slightly refactor the generated code and recreating the entire thing overwrites it all.

Comment: In that case, have a look at the EF Reverse POCO template, which allows you to do table renames up front

Comment: @ErikEJ Hi, how to rerun the wizard? Do I have to delete the context and add a new one?